# How to let Graphics3D show texts only within the plot range?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

MMA Version: 10.3.0.0

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {0, 0, 0}]}, 
           PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

will give

[image: text is outside the plot range]

while I would like to expect the same behavior as `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Text[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {0, 0}]}, 
         PlotRange -> {{-0.04, 1.01}, {-0.05, 1}}]
```

which shows only part of the text:

[image: only part of the text is shown]

So can I make `Graphics3D` show texts only within the plot range (with MMA v10.3+)?

Comment: Why do you want to cut off text if it happens to be outside the frame?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have a `Graphics3D` object and I want to have a "zoomed-in" version for some part of it. The texts outside will be annoying (they are hovering in the air without the graphics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mma v9 the behavior was what you expected

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {0, 0, 0}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {0.5, 0.7, 1}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 10, you need to use `ImagePadding->None` to reproduce this effect,

```
    Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {0, 0, 0}]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
       ImagePadding -> #] & /@ {Automatic, None}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {0.5, 0.7, 1}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image]